# Why is the logistic regression model good? (and its relation with maximizing entropy)

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, machine-learning

Suppose we're trying to train a classifier $\pi$ for $k$ classes that takes as input a feature vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and outputs a probability vector $\pi(x)\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\sum_{v=1}^k \pi(x)_v = 1$ and $\pi(x)_v\in [0,1]$ is the probability that the object with features $x$ belongs to the $v$th class.

The standard logistic model for such a classifier uses the function $\pi(x)$ whose $v$th component is given by

$$\pi(x)_v = \frac{e^{\lambda_v\cdot x}}{\sum_{u=1}^k e^{\lambda_u\cdot x}}$$

for some weight vector $\lambda_v\in\mathbb{R}^k$. If $k = 2$ and $\lambda_2 = 0$, then this is just the sigmoid function in $\lambda_1\cdot x$. If our training data consists of feature vectors $x(1),\ldots,x(m)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and classifications $y(1),\ldots,y(n)\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$, then logistic regression would have us choose the weights $\lambda_v$ to maximize the product
$$\prod_{i=1}^m\pi(x(i))_{y(i)}$$
which is the probability that the model correctly classifies each item in the training data. Apparently, under mild hypotheses, the maximum value is attained at a unique $\lambda = (\lambda_v)_{v = 1,\ldots,k}$.

My basic question is: *In what sense is this an optimal model?* One answer, which I learned from [these notes by John Mount](https://github.com/WinVector/Examples/blob/main/dfiles/LogisticRegressionMaxEnt.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3gW9YMPcR_aEcAqNunRFi-Kyycgs_IUyv3vJYft6hKJ5k_V5o3U9_W98Y), is that when restricted to a subclass of classifiers satisfying a certain "balance condition" (described below), this model is the one that maximizes entropy over the training set. If the training set consists of the feature vectors $x(1),\ldots,x(m)$, then this model maximizes the quantity
$$-\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{v=1}^k \pi(x(i))_v\log \pi(x)_v$$
I accept that maximizing entropy makes sense philosophically, but this shifts our attention to the balance condition, which would require:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \pi(x(i))_u x(i)_j = \sum_{i=1}^m \delta(u,y(i))x(i)_j\qquad\text{for all $u,j$}$$
where $\delta(a,b) = 1$ if $a = b$, and 0 otherwise.

Why is it reasonable to restrict our attention to functions which satisfy these balance conditions?

Comment: Normally there's an intercept parameter, thus: $$\pi(x)_v = \frac{e^{\alpha + \lambda_v\cdot x}}{\sum_{u=1}^k e^{\alpha + \lambda_u\cdot x}}$$ This is not trivially equivalent to the form that omits $\alpha$ because $\alpha$ is not part of the observed data but, like $\lambda,$ must be estimated by maximizing the product that you mentioned.

Comment: I'll probably post an answer here within a few days.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That would be great!

Comment: This question has caused me to realize that I'm rusty in certain things.

Answer (score 1):

On the space $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_v)\in(0,1)^v : x_1+\cdots + x_v=1\},$ introduce an operation of addition as follows:
$$
\mathbf a \mathbin{\text{“}{+}\text{”}} \mathbf b =(a_1,\ldots,a_v) \mathbin{\text{“}{+}\text{”}} (b_1,\ldots,b_v) = \frac{(a_1b_1,\ldots, a_vb_v)}{a_1b_1+\cdots +a_vb_v}.
$$
Now we have a vector space (where it is now easy to see what the scalar multiplication will be).

If $\mathbf a = \big( \Pr(A_1), \ldots, \Pr(A_v) \big)$ and $\mathbf b \propto \big( \Pr(D\mid A_1),\ldots, \Pr(D\mid A_v) \big) $ then $\mathbf a \mathbin{\text{“}{+}\text{”}} \mathbf b = \big( \Pr(A_1\mid D),\ldots, \Pr(A_v\mid D) \big).$

Thus the arrival of new data $D$ corresponds to a **translation** in this vector space.

With this structure, the mapping to be estimated, from $x\in\mathbb R^n$ to the smaller $(v-1)$-dimensional vector space, and that is estimated by maximizing the product that was mentioned, is **affine.**

(If I'm not mistaken, the numerical algorithm used for this is "iteratively reweighted least squares", but the weights to which the algorithm converges depend on the data—the observed values of the $x$s and the categories, so this is not the same as what is usually called weighted least squares.)

Comment: Maybe I'll add some more here later.